# Pycharm - Pyramid debugging request

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid, pycharm

I am using Pycharm as IDE for one of my projects. The framework of choice is Pyramid and here comes my issue. I am not able to debug the request using PyCharm even though I start the application in debug mode. When a request is made from the browser the breakpoints from the views.py are not hit this does not apply for the breakpoints set in the application start-up (**init**.py and initializedb.py). Please note that I am new on Pyramid. Any idea how to solve this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I apologize for not mentioning the details. I am using PyCharm 3.02 Pro and Pyramid 1.4.5. I am using the scaffolding provided by PyCharm.

Comment: Which version of PyCharm and Pyramid?  Also are you using any Pyramid scaffold, or do you use your own code?  This question is impossible to answer with the information provided.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question.

Comment: PyCharm has documentation for how to run in debug mode.  Did you consult that?  Not sure whether you mean the PyCharm app or a web browser by the term "browser".  For the actual code, which scaffold name? There are 3 scaffolds in Pyramid 1.4.5, and PyCharm does not provide scaffolds.  Finally, are you following a tutorial or some other Pyramid documentation?

Comment: @Steve, that's odd, in my case PyCharm does provide scaffold for Pyramid. If I navigate to New Project in the opened new project window I have the option to choose what project type I want to create, and Pyramid is one of them. I have checked both sources (PyCharm docs and Pyramid docs).

Comment: Just as a reference check the following: http://pauleveritt.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/pycharm-3-0-eap2-supports-pyramid/

Comment: Also on JetBrain site if you read PyCharm Pro summary you can notice that it supports PyCharm. http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/index.html

Comment: PyCharm has _support_ for Pyramid.  In his blog, Paul states "Choosing one of the Pyramid-provided 'scaffolds' to generate a working sample".  See the official Pyramid docs on [creating a Pyramid project using a scaffold](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html#scaffolds-included-with-pyramid).  So, no, PyCharm does not provide scaffolds, Pyramid does.  Using proper terminology is important so that people understand you and can help you when you have questions.

Comment: I assumed that the terms are interchangeable :)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have figured it out. It was my fault. The project gets deployed as an egg so that's where I was suppose to place my breakpoints.
Thanks a lot for your time and consideration.